# RenderFooter called infinitely

Tags: react-native, listview, android-recyclerview, react-native-flatlist

When I reach the bottom of FlipKarts recyclerlistview it enters an infinite loop calling renderFooter thousands of times and I cant scroll up anymore.... No idea what this could be. It should scroll to the bottom and then simply bounce up or just stay at the bottom. Instead it gets stuck and Ive found nothing on github or stackoverflow.

```
    renderFooter() {
        if(this.state.outPosts == false) {
            return <View style={{
                alignContent:'center', 
                justifyContent:'center', 
                alignItems:'center', 
            }}>
                <ActivityIndicator 
                    style={{
                        marginTop:15*factor_ver,
                        marginBottom:15*factor_ver,
                    }} 
                    size={"small"}
                    color={'#9b9b9b'}
                />
            </View>
        }
        else if(this.state.outPosts == true) {
            return <View style={{
                        height:140*factor_hor, 
                        marginTop:20, 
                        alignContent:'center', 
                        justifyContent:'center', 
                        alignItems:'center', 
                    }}>
                        <Text style={{textAlign:'center', fontSize:22*factor_hor, fontFamily:'Avenir Next', color:'#9b9b9b',}}>
                            No posts! :(
                        </Text>
                        <View style={{flex:1,}}></View>
                        <Block width={60*factor_hor}
                            height={60*factor_hor}
                            style={{
                                justifyContent:'center',
                                alignContent:'center',
                                flex: 1,
                        }}
                        />
                        <View style={{height:30}}></View>
                    </View> 
        }
    }


                    <RecyclerListView 
                        style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'#f7f7f7', paddingTop:8*factor_hor,}}
                        extendedState={this.state}
                        rowRenderer={this._renderRow} 
                        dataProvider={this.state.dataProvider}
                        layoutProvider={this._layoutProvider}
                        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                        onEndReached={() => this.fetchPosts()}
                        onEndReachedThreshold={500}
                        renderFooter={this.renderFooter}
                        onScroll={(e) => this.handleScroll(e)}
                        scrollThrottle={250}
                        refreshControl={
                        <RefreshControl
                            tintColor={'white'}
                            refreshing={false}
                            onRefresh={() => { 
                                this.setState({isLoad:true}), this.refresh_feed()}} 
                        />}
                    />
```

Answer (score 0):

great so Im going to leave this up here because theres nothing else I could find to explain this. If youre using React native FlipKart recyclerlistview and you render empty views then when you scroll to the bottom this glitch happens where you cant scroll up and renderFooter is called infinitely. Check to make sure each rendered view has at least a container to fill it.